# substring javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
//Example I passed in 31-02-2013
//var timeDate = document.getElementById('date').text; <--This Wont Work!
//This is some very basic example only. Badly formatted user entry will cause all 
//sorts of problems.
var timeDate = document.getElementById('date').value;

//Get First 2 Characters 
var first2 = timeDate.substring(0,2);
console.log(first2);

var dateArray = timeDate.split("-");
console.log(dateArray[0]);

var date = parseInt(dateArray[0], 10) ;//Make sure you use the radix otherwise leading 0 will hurt
console.log(date);
if( date < 1 || date > 30 )
    alert( "Invalid date" );

var month2 = timeDate.substring(3,5);
console.log( month2 );

var monthArray = timeDate.split( "-" );
console.log( monthArray[1] );

var month = parseInt( monthArray[1],10 );
console.log( month );

if( month < 1 || month > 12 )
    alert( "Invalid month" );
}
</script>
```

My function is working, just i want to some correction like if user input
-23-11-2013 // <--This won't work as the first alphabet is "-"

My text input only accept the date that
23-11-2013 // <---Will Work.

but for my function if i insert the date like -23-11-2013
it will show invalid month . what should i do some changes for my function

Comment: Can you create fiddle of this ?

Comment: What exactly do you want your function to do? Simply strip a possible *hyphen* at the beginning of the input string?

Answer (score 0):

Check the javascript substring function [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

My example : results in `est`

```
var a ="test";
console.log(a.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

var date = "-23-11-2013";

data = date.split("-");

if(data.length == 3){

if(Number(data[0])>31){

alert("invalid date format");

}else if(Number(data[1])>12){

alert("invalid month format");

} 
}else{

alert("incorrect format");

}

Answer (score 0):

He is a better function you could perhaps use:

```
function myFunc(s) {

   s = s.split("-").filter(Number); 

   return new Date(s[2], s[1], s[0]);
}
```

It should either return **Invalid Date** or a **Date object.**

So a call like `myFunc("23-11-2013")` or `myFunc("-23-11-2013")` should return a **Date object**:

```
Mon Dec 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better function that you can use:

```
function myFunction(date) {
  var args = date.split(/[^0-9]+/),
      i, l = args.length;

  // Prepare args
  for(i=0;i<l;i++) {
    if(!args[i]) {
      args.splice(i--,1);
      l--;
    } else {
      args[i] = parseInt(args[i], 10);
    }
  }

  // Check month
  if(args[1] < 1 || args[1] > 12) {
    throw new Error('Invalid month');
  }
  // Check day (passing day 0 to Date constructor returns last day of previous month)
  if(args[0] > new Date(args[2], args[1], 0).getDate()) {
    throw new Error('Invalid date');
  }

  return new Date(args[2], args[1]-1, args[0]); 
}
```

Pay attention that month in `Date` constructor is `0` based and you need to subtract `1` from actual value. Besides of it you have wrong day check since different months have different number of days. Provided function also allows to pass values like `-23 - 11/2013` with spaces and special characters, the only thing matters is the order of numbers (day, month, year).

Here you can see it working http://jsbin.com/umacal/3/edit